Rstudio:Tensorflow and Keras both installed but failed to load due to No module named 'tensorflow'
I am now working on my class essay and I'm trying to create a CNN in RStudio.
At first the No module named tensorflow error message appeared when I tried to run the code:
layer_dense(units=1,activation ='linear')

However, after I tried to set the python environment following ChatGPT's guidance, the failure appears right at the first piece of code when I ran:
library(keras)

Even when I run library(tensorflow) first, it still appears.
Can anyone please helppppppp? 
py_config()
python:         C:/Users/32062/Documents/.virtualenvs/r-reticulate/Scripts/python.exe
libpython:      C:/Users/32062/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python310.dll
pythonhome:     C:/Users/32062/Documents/.virtualenvs/r-reticulate
version:        3.10.6 (tags/v3.10.6:9c7b4bd, Aug  1 2022, 21:53:49) [MSC v.1932 64 bit (AMD64)]
Architecture:   64bit
numpy:          C:/Users/32062/Documents/.virtualenvs/r-reticulate/Lib/site-packages/numpy
numpy_version:  2.2.0


I can't believe chatgpt's guidance has got you into this pickle! . Have you actually installed keras manually? I'm not overly familiar with the setup you're using here since it's based on reticulate

Actually, lots of this is unclear to me. Do you have any other additional output? It looks like Rstudio has linked to a virtualenv of python but I'm not at all sure how that works

Are you trying to do this? If so, are you actually intending to operate between both R and Python, or are you just looking to work in Python?

This problem is not unique to you. Many R Studio users often encounter this compatibility issue when trying to install and load either keras or tensorflow likely because of the way their python environment is setup on their machine. There are two possible solutions: 1) Install and load both libraries in Positron instead of R Studio (I just tried it and it worked). 2) If your code isn't proprietary, you can use the R runtime on Google Colab. It works perfectly for running keras and tensorflow code in R.

@roganjosh Um sorry about everything, I'm kinda new here and it even takes me a while to figure out how to reply u(

py_run_string("import sys;sys.stderr.flush();sys.stdout.flush()")
reticulate::repl_python()
Python 3.10.6 (C:/Users/32062/Documents/.virtualenvs/r-reticulate/Scripts/python.exe)
Reticulate 1.40.0 REPL -- A Python interpreter in R.
Enter 'exit' or 'quit' to exit the REPL and return to R.


reticulate::repl_python()
File "", line 1
reticulate::repl_python()
^




@AngelaChen no need to be sorry :) I'm just trying to get my head around what it is that you're doing. ChatGPT frequently gives out bad advice so I'm trying to figure out the foundations of what you're trying to do and move forwards from there

@roganjosh >>> py_run_string("import sys;sys.stdout.flush()")
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
NameError: name 'py_run_string' is not defined



library(keras)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
NameError: name 'library' is not defined
exit




@roganjosh And also I tried to use cmd to download Tensorflow according to Chatgpt, my brain's kinda messed up aaaaaa I'm dead( Thank you for ur help
C:\Users\32062>pip install tensorflow
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000028D16DDD2A0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061]

You're probably on a VPN that's blocking the connection. Turn it off

@roganjosh Thank u sirit's now downloading, I will try to manage everything when it finishes, have a good day

@Ifeanyi Idiaye Thank u sir, I will try latr, have a nice day❤️‍
